# ogrinfo bash script failure

Tags: ogr, find

I need to recursively document a bunch of Shapefiles using orginfo in many directories. For example,

```
$ tree -P *.shp
.
├── acfish2s
│   └── acfish2.shp
├── airports
│   ├── airport_runways.shp
│   └── airports.shp
├── aquifer_contactss
│   └── aquifer_contacts.shp
├── aquifer_polygonss
│   └── aquifer_polygons.shp
├── armoriess
│   └── armories.shp
├── ashab3s
│   └── ashab3.shp
```

I've found something that works for the first layer, but then dies with "FAILURE: Couldn't fetch requested layer".

```
from ~/airports
$ find ./* -type f -name \*.shp | xargs -0 /bin/GDAL/./ogrinfo.exe -ro -so -fields=YES -geom=SUMMARY $x ${x%.*}
INFO: Open of `airports.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: airports
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 212
Extent: (341172.066500, 4778235.208900) - (656874.933400, 5237120.513500)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_19N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-69.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
SITENUMBER: String (254.0)
<snip>
DOTID: Integer (10.0)
FAILURE: Couldn't fetch requested layer ./airport_runways.shp
./airports.shp
!
```

when I do it from a higher level, I get the following error

```
$ find ./* -type f -name \*.shp | xargs /bin/GDAL/./ogrinfo.exe -ro -so -fields=YES -geom=SUMMARY $x ${x%.*}
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `airports.shp' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
<snip>
```

I was thinking it was a BASH thing, but the stat command (mostly) works.

```
$ find ./* -type f -name \*.shp | xargs stat $x
stat: cannot stat `airports.shp': No such file or directory
  File: `./acfish2s/acfish2.shp'
  Size: 11428           Blocks: 12         IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: b054e692h/2958354066d   Inode: 844424930137000  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (57187/john.zastrow)   Gid: (10513/Domain Users)
Access: 2005-03-18 10:38:56.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2005-03-18 10:38:56.000000000 -0500
Change: 2012-11-27 00:09:45.025730200 -0500
 Birth: 2012-11-27 00:09:44.967726900 -0500
  File: `./airports/airports.shp'
  Size: 6036            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: b054e692h/2958354066d   Inode: 844424930137006  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (57187/john.zastrow)   Gid: (10513/Domain Users)
Access: 2011-03-02 08:51:18.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2011-03-02 08:51:18.000000000 -0500
Change: 2012-11-27 00:09:45.365749700 -0500
 Birth: 2012-11-27 00:09:45.304746200 -0500
  File: `./airports/airport_runways.shp'
  Size: 32960           Blocks: 36         IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: b054e692h/2958354066d   Inode: 281474976715722  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (57187/john.zastrow)   Gid: (10513/Domain Users)
Access: 2011-03-02 08:50:58.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2011-03-02 08:50:58.000000000 -0500
Change: 2012-11-27 00:09:48.799946100 -0500
 Birth: 2012-11-27 00:09:48.735942400 -0500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback. I forgot about the xargs stuff, but had issues with the bash string manipulation (I'm running on Cygwin in windows...). So I switched approaches and came up with this little ditty.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "********************** START Shapefiles ***********************"
echo ""
    for x in $(find ./* -type f -name \*.shp); do
        base=${x##*/}
        echo "--- Found the Shapefile " $base "and the base layer of " ${base%.*}
        /bin/GDAL/./ogrinfo.exe -ro -so -al -fields=YES -geom=SUMMARY $x
    echo ""
done
echo ""
echo "********************** END Shapefiles ***********************"

echo "********************** START TIFFs ***********************"
echo ""
    for y in $(find ./* -type f -name \*.tif); do
        base=${y##*/}
        echo "--- Found the TIFF file " $base "and the base layer of " ${base%.*}
        /bin/GDAL/./gdalinfo.exe -approx_stats -mm -noct -proj4 $y
    echo ""
done
echo ""
echo "********************** END TIFFs ***********************"
```

which outputs things like this for a TIFF

```
--- Found the TIFF file  melcd_2004_imperviousness.tif and the base layer of          melcd_2004_imperviousness
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: ./Land_Characteristics/impervs/melcd_2004_imperviousness.tif
       ./Land_Characteristics/impervs/melcd_2004_imperviousness.tfw
       ./Land_Characteristics/impervs/melcd_2004_imperviousness.aux
Size is 65102, 99355
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["UTM",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-69],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["meters",1],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","26919"]]
PROJ.4 string is:
'+proj=utm +zone=19 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs '
Origin = (336631.500000000000000,5256292.500000000000000)
Pixel Size = (5.000000000000000,-5.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IMAGINE TIFF Support
Copyright 1991 - 1999 by ERDAS, Inc. All Rights Reserved
@(#)$RCSfile: etif.c $ $Revision: 1.10.1.9.1.9.2.11 $ $Date: 2004/09/15 18:42:01EDT $
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=0.2
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=0.2
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=CCITTRLE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  336631.500, 5256292.500) ( 71d10' 0.27"W, 47d26'22.55"N)
Lower Left  (  336631.500, 4759517.500) ( 71d 0'12.02"W, 42d58'14.82"N)
Upper Right (  662141.500, 5256292.500) ( 66d50'58.28"W, 47d26'23.65"N)
Lower Right (  662141.500, 4759517.500) ( 67d 0'42.12"W, 42d58'15.76"N)
Center      (  499386.500, 5007905.000) ( 69d 0'28.13"W, 45d13'28.69"N)
Band 1 Block=65102x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Description = Band_1
  Min=0.000 Max=1.000   Computed Min/Max=0.000,1.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=1.000, Mean=0.992, StdDev=0.091
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.99165311862261
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN=0
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_MODE=1.9020308565413e-230
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.090979178661602
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=1
  Color Table (RGB with 2 entries)
<GDALRasterAttributeTable />
```

and things like this for a Shapefile

```
    ********************** START Shapefiles ***********************
    --- Found the Shapefile  acfish2.shp and the base layer of  acfish2
    INFO: Open of `./Bio_Eco_Cons/acfish2s/acfish2.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: acfish2
Geometry: Multi Point
Feature Count: 177
Extent: (356761.978694, 4771813.744319) - (653088.978694, 5004932.744319)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_19N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-69.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
ACFISH2_ID: Integer (9.0)
DMR_ID: String (5.0)
ECCM_ID: String (5.0)
YEAR: String (4.0)
ECCM_SP: String (10.0)
USFW_SP: String (10.0)
DMR_SP: String (10.0)
DMR_NAME: String (30.0)
```

now I just need to see about getting this working with File geodatabases.

Answer (score 3):

It's an xargs thing, specifically you need to use '-print0' with find and '-n1' with xargs.

This worked for me on linux, see if that works for you.

```
find ./* -type f -name \*.shp -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 /bin/GDAL/./ogrinfo.exe -ro -so -fields=YES -geom=SUMMARY $x ${x%.*}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following should also work with `tree`:

```
for file in `tree -f -i | grep .shp`
   do ogrinfo -ro -so -fields=YES -geom=SUMMARY $file
done
```

Depending on your requirements, you may want to redirect the output to a text file.